# Maven discovery completed without finding any extensions

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, m2e

I have installed eclipse 4.3 on my system and recently installed the Maven integration plugin. I get the following error:

> Discovery completed without finding any extensions. Please check your network connection and try again.

The catalog url is `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.4.xml`

**Note**: No proxies, no network issues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a Java update 1.7.0_45 which fixes that problem.

Comment: I am still encountering the error after updating Java; Java: 1.8.0_241, Windows 10: 17763, Eclipse: 4.9.0.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with eclipse-kepler and Java 1.7_40 update.  I resolved it by reverting to an older (Java 1.6) version of Java.

You can find more details here about the details causing the issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417241

Hope this helps
~J