# Add a Mavenproject in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, plugins

[image]Hi evevryone,

I am trying to add a maven project with Eclipse.
I have just installed eclipse Java EE Kepler.
I have also inlcuded the SVN and Maven Plug In for eclipse.
When I try to add an existing Maven project I cannot select the SVN repository. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I really find more comfortable checking out source from command line, and then importing the projects in Eclipse. Anyway, did you install Maven scm handler for the SVN eclipse implementation you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom right, hit **m2e Marketplace** and install the connector you need ;)

Comment: When I do it I get the error: Discovery completed without finding any extensions. Please check your network connection and try again.

Comment: what java version do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131143/maven-discovery-completed-without-finding-any-extensions check this out. You may need to do an upgrade or downgrade of your jdk